# System of equations with steps included

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hello I've been trying to get a system of equation that look like the picture above but haven't found anything. What I've found is with circles and without steps shown on the left of the equations. This is a code I've tried but does not look similiar to what I want:

```
    \newcommand\mess[2][20pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,yshift=22pt,xshift=#1,black]
  \node[circle,draw,black,inner sep=1pt] (a) {$#2$};
  \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (a.south) |- ([yshift=-9pt,xshift=-#1]a.south);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
    \phantom{0}x_1+2x_2-2x_3=1 \\
    2x_1-\phantom{0}x_2+\phantom{0}x_3=3\mess{-2}\\
    \phantom{0}x_1+3x_2+\phantom{0}x_3=1\mess[40pt]{-1}
\end{cases}\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get square instead circle just remove `circle` from the node's option and set `inner sep=3pt` to increase the height of the box.

I found a solution to put *times a* on the left side via `tikzmarks`. You have to load

`\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}`

Then the register a position on the left of the desired equation by `\tikzmark{a}` and you recall this at the end by

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[xshift=-.7cm,yshift=2pt] (a) at (pic cs:a){$a\cdot$};
\node[xshift=-.7cm,yshift=2pt] (b) at (pic cs:b){$a\cdot$};
}
```

You have to compile the code twice.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\phantom{0}x_1+2x_2-2x_3=1 \\
\tikzmark{a}2x_1-\phantom{0}x_2+\phantom{0}x_3=3\\
\tikzmark{b}\phantom{0}x_1+3x_2+\phantom{0}x_3=1{-1}
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow\quad
\begin{cases}
\phantom{0}x_1+2x_2-2x_3=1 \\
2x_1-\phantom{0}x_2+\phantom{0}x_3=3\mess{-2}\\
\phantom{0}x_1+3x_2+\phantom{0}x_3=1\mess[40pt]{-1}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[xshift=-.7cm,yshift=2pt] (a) at (pic cs:a){$a\cdot$};
\node[xshift=-.7cm,yshift=2pt] (b) at (pic cs:b){$a\cdot$};
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I move the -1 box up to where -2 box is?

Answer (score 1):

I propose this simple solution, with the `system` package and `pstricks`. Additionally, I think the framed coefficients would look better in `medium size`, which can be done with the `\medsize` command from `nccmath` (ca 80% of \displaystyle):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools, systeme}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\newcommand{\myfnode}[2]{\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.6pt}\rnode{#1}{\fbox{$\medmath{#2}$}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \systeme {x_1 + 2x_2-2x_3 = 1, 2x_1-x_2 + x_3 = \rnode{L2}{3}, x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = \rnode{L3}{1}}\qquad\begin{aligned}
 & \myfnode{c2}{-2} & &\myfnode{c3}{-1} \\ \\ \mbox{}
\end{aligned}
\psset{angleA=-90, angleB=0, nodesepB=3pt, linewidth=0.6pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12}
\ncangle{c2}{L2}\ncangle{c3}{L3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure but there's no arrows using the code on Overleaf!

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bKnv2ZO.png This is what I get using your code

Comment: Which engine did you compile with? latex ->dvips -> pstopdf?